# Is Manu Smriti anti-brahmin? "A brahmin who drank alcohol must drink red-hot wine until his body is fully burnt", but no such punishment for Shudras?

Tags: brahmins, manu-smriti, shudra

[Manu Smriti 11.90](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201969.html)

> सुरां पीत्वा द्विजो मोहादग्निवर्णां सुरां पिबेत् ।
> तया स काये निर्दग्धे मुच्यते किल्बिषात् ततः ॥ ९० ॥
>
> surāṃ pītvā dvijo mohādagnivarṇāṃ surāṃ pibet |
> tayā sa kāye nirdagdhe
> mucyate kilbiṣāt tataḥ || 90 ||
>
> A twice-born person, having, through folly, drunk wine, shall drink
> wine red-hot;
> he becomes freed from his guilt, when **his body has been
> completely burnt by it**.

But no such punishment is prescribed for Shudras. So they're free to enjoy.

Even other Rishis agree with Manu:

Gautama (23.1).—"**They shall pour hot wine into the mouth of a Brāhmaṇa** who has drunk wine; he will be purified by death."

Baudhāyana (2.1.18, 19, 21).—"If he has drunk Surā he shall **scald himself to death with hot wine**."

Āpastamba (1.25.3).—"A wine-drinker **has to drink exceedingly hot liquor, so that he dies**."

**Is Manu Smriti anti-brahmin ?**
Are these rishis also anti-brahmin ?

Manu was not a Brahmin. He was Kshatriya. Why do brahmins follow a scripture that does not even allow them simple pleasures of life, and instead mandates death penalty just for drinking some booze ?

Comment: Because protecting dharma needs loads of discipline and focused mind. IMO these enjoyment can not take the Brahmins any closer to their duties. That's why I think these punishment were enforced in manu Smriti.

Comment: One verse doesnt proove anything. What about verses which say Sudras cant earn money, Sudra can be made to do anything which a Bramhin wants, Sudra should wear torn clothes , cant even sit on same seat as Dvijas, killed for adultery but Bramhin just fined ? And if anyone does a sin donate to Bramhins, Dont tax to Bramhins ? And then they cant even recite Vedas but massage feet of Bramhins and serve like a Menial as per Mahabharata ? And a Bramhin even if vile conduct to be respected and Sudra even if best conduct cant be admired ? Tonnes of such verses.

Comment: Munis cursing Gods like Yama to be born as Sudras. Chandalas should only burn corpses but a Bramhin gets everything as donations from kings. And Rama gifting Servant Girls and mountains of Gold to Bramhins ? And a Sudra cant even have choise to select his name and his first name should be "Disgusting" as per Manu. I am born in a Bramhin family. I loved Hinduism more than my life. But I start getting tears seeing how my ancestors were responsible for this inhumane practices. A Sudra cant even have a fire in Marriage time. Obviously they will convert to other religions.

Comment: Think honestly if you were a Sudra or a Chandala would you accept such inhumane treatment ? I would never because its the Conscience in me or Rta which tells me its wrong.

Comment: No personal attack please. @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: I never did any personal attack @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: "Think honestly if you were a Sudra or a Chandala would you accept such inhumane treatment ? I would never because its the Conscience in me or Rta which tells me its wrong." <---------------- @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru You are just looking at all the "anti shudra" verses, but I can also cherry pick dozens of "anti brahmin" verses. Shudras can eat garlic, onion, liquor. They can wake up at anytime. And btw brahmins can't earn money either. Only vaishyas main job is to earn profit. Brahmin and shudra should only earn enough money for sustenance. Rest go to charity. Because of these restrictions, would not brahmins convert to Christianity?

Comment: When there are 1000s of Anti Sudra verses and few Anti Bramhin verses will it matter sir ? Parashara Smriti says "even if Bramhin doesnt follow his duties he will still be a Bramhin and deserves more respect than a Learned Sudra for Dog is Dog." And if someone does a Sin Smritis say Donate to Bramhins. Kings give mountains of Gold(as per Epics) and Servants. And it continues. I am also born in a Bramhana family. But I am wise enough to realise that True Dharma Satya Rta can never cause unhappyness in society. Imagine if you were born as Chandala/Sudra. How would you feel if..

Comment: Others dont even treat you as Human. Bhisma says "Knowing how painful it is one must never do such acts to others" Chandalas living isolated and Smritis saying they are outcasted because their father Sudras married Bramhin women , How is that justified ?? Lets imagine ourselves in their position. And irnoy is a Sudra cant even have fire worship during his marriage and has to keep his name as "Disgusting". Its another fact that Smritis were never implemented and Sudras were Kings; But that doesnt whitewash injustice of Smritis. Adultery is adultery but V1 spared and V$ killed.

Comment: What authority we have to punish someone throughout his life to burn corpses and lead such disgusting life ? Today every one hates me and my ancestors because of wrongdoings they did. I cant appolozize nor do anything. I can only recognize and put faith in Devas Rta and Dharma. @Ikshvaku

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru Obviously the authority is shastra. People are born in those castes and do those dirty jobs as punishment for past life sins.

Comment: Please lets assume ourselves in their position. Would we accept even in dreams to do such jobs which are forced on us ? Freedom of expression thought and ability to manifest such skill as per man's wish must always be there.  We must give every Indian the fullest opportunity to develop himself according to his capacity. Imagine what would Chandalas think of Hindus when they are forced to wear second hand old clothes and not even allowed to walk on Roads and change their Jobs. Think sir open your heart. Dharma and Rta can be seen. @Ikshvaku

Comment: Sir one Dalit asked me " You people only ring bells in temples and sit in place and read. WE clean gutters and do much hardwork than you and we have doing this " These things make me very guilty and sad @Ikshvaku

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru - Do you believe in karma & rebirth ? Suppose an old man commits a murder, but none finds out, then he enjoys remaining days of his life and dies naturally. Should he get punished for the murder, yes or no ?

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru - please put yourself in the place of a thief. would you accept even in dreams to be confined in jail for 20 years ? freedom to roam about the world must always be there. we must give every thief the fullest opportunity to develop himself according to his capacity. Imagine what thieves would think of police & constitution if they are forced to stay inside cell for 20 hours a day. Open your heart. Let us free all thieves.

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru "WE clean gutters and do much hardwork than you and we have doing this" - there are gutter cleaners in every country FYI. Someone has to clean gutters. Do you think gutter cleaners like their job or picked it? They clean gutters because they have no other choice.

Comment: Bro, used uno reverse card for bhimtas, still nice question

Comment: there are no gutter cleaning jobs in any of the dharmashastras. All dharmashastras detail out jobs for shudras/mixedcastes and all of those jobs are vocational  ones. Brahmin has to cook food by himself and void excrements in pig toilet, so it is clear that brahmana cannot not employ shudra for any menial job & service rendered by shudra is a professional service. Brahmin cannot charge interest on loan lent but a shudra can charge interest on loan lent (manu X.116). Brahmin has to allot property to shudra (manu X.124). Net income for a brahmin is much lower than shudra.